# jquery url not replacing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have jquery regex that finds the web address URL at the top and replaces it with a new url, however the regex that I have written changes the url but regex is adding other the extra stuff from the URL at the end. It's adding `3543463456546456` at well instead of `https://127.0.0.1/id=12345`

```
<script>
 var urlTest = $(location).attr("href");
 var test1 = urlTest.replace(/https:\/\/127.0.0.1\/test1\/test2\/(12345)\/3543463456546456/g, "https://127.0.0.1/id=$1");
 $(".test").append(document.write(test1));
</script>
```

Not sure why its picking up 3543463456546456

Comment: Why `document.write(test1)`?! [`.append`](https://api.jquery.com/append/) expects a string, element, or jQuery object (or array thereof, or function), but _not `undefined`_. It’s `$(".test").append(test1);`. Never use `document.write`. `document.write` is [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/802854/4642212) for DOM manipulations, as it is obsolete, slow and not suitable for any evolving application.

Comment: Your regexp only replaces the beginning of the URL. If there's more after the matched portion it will be left in the result.

Comment: What is the original value of `urlTest`?

Comment: original value for urlTest is whatever the location of the url is on the web address bar. It could be https://127.0.0.1/test1/test2/12345/3543463456546456 or https://127.0.0.1/test1/test2/67890/6546456543643453  I'm wanting to capture just https://127.0.0.1/test1/test2/67890 and convert it to https://127.0.0.1/id=67890 without the extra characters at the end

Comment: Adding to my first comment, if `$(".test").append`, doesn’t work: is your `<script>` _above_ your HTML with no `defer` attribute and no `DOMContentLoaded` or `load` listener? See [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as `getElementById` not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/4642212).

Comment: I was able to figure it out. I added .* to the regex